# Why is MySQL looking for colum with name of value inserting

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery

When doing a cfquery to MySQL, MYSQL gives me the error Unknown column 'Question' in 'field list' on the following code:

```
<cfquery name="qUpdateTheQuestion" datasource="testmaster">
INSERT INTO ETrueFalseQuestions
VALUES (<cfoutput>#newTypeID#</cfoutput>, `<cfoutput>#FORM.Question#</cfoutput>`, <cfoutput>#FORM.truefalse#</cfoutput>
```

I have tried everything I could think of to try to solve this issue, as well as some suggestions I found when trying to search for a solution, such as using backticks instead of single quotes.

I also don't understand why it is searching for a column with the name Question, as that is the value of FORM.Question, and changes depending on what is typed into the form. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please wrap your variables in `cfqueryparam`: `<cfqueryparam value="#newTypeID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INT" />`, `<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.question#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />`, `<cfqueryparam value="#FORM.truefalse#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIT" />`

Comment: Re: *why it is searching for a column with the name Question* `FORM.Question` contains a string. Literal strings must be enclosed in single quotes (or wrapped in cfqueryparam), otherwise your database assumes it is an object name ie Column or table name. Also, you never need `cfoutput` tags within a cfquery.

Comment: Used the cfqueryparam, but is there some advantage to this over just using the variables?

Comment: `cfqueryparam` gives these advantages: protection against SQL-injection attacks _and_ using bind variables which allows the database to re-use compiled queries and, thus, improve performance.

Comment: The `<cfoutput>`s you're using are also unnecessary inside a `cfquery` tag.

Comment: So, is it a security issue to select all of the fields, including the password field, when logging in a user? Is it somehow possible to get this.

Answer (score 7):

that query makes no sense to me

normally it should look like

```
INSERT INTO ETrueFalseQuestions (IdColumnName, questionColumnName, questionTrueFalse)     
VALUES ( #newTypeID#, '#form.Question#', #form.truefalse# )
```

So you need to

1. list the columns
2. not use `<cfoutput>` within a `<cfquery>`
3. put single quotes around string values or use `<cfqueryparam>`

PS: the column names I used are made up you need to fix them to match yours.

Comment: I would also add what s992 mentioned above. Use cfqueryparam.

Comment: ditto to scott's ans s992 suggestion.